# Odata $top doesn't work with MongoDb

Tags: odata, mongodb-.net-driver

I've stuck into some weird problem. Here is the code
AccountsController.cs

```
// GET /api/accounts
[HttpGet]
[Queryable(ResultLimit = 50)]
public IQueryable<AccountDto> Get()
{
    return this.service.Get();
}
```

service here - it's AccountService.cs

```
public IQueryable<AccountDto> Get()
{
    return this.readModel.Get();
}
```

and readModel is of type AccountsReadModel

```
public IQueryable<AccountDto> Get()
{
    return Database.GetCollection<AccountDto>("Accounts").AsQueryable();
}
```

Database is MongoDb.Driver.Database

the problem is following:
when I trying to query Get method without any parameters - 
`localhost/api/accounts` - it returns all accounts (as intended)
when I use skip: `localhost/api/accounts?$skip=n` - it skips n and returns rest items
(as intended too)
but, `localhost/api/accounts?$top=1` returns all accounts, instead of one.

How can I handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in **[Queryable(ResultLimit=50)]:**

it and `$top=1` together produces following expression:
`coll.Take(1).Take(50)` which returns not 1, but 50 (or all elements in collection, in case if there are less elements than 50).
By the way, `Database.GetCollection<A>("A").AsQueryable().Take(1).Take(50)` - returns not 1 element again.
This looks like bug in MongoDbDriver

Answer (score 0):

use with `$orderby`

```
localhost/api/accounts?$top=1&$orderby=...
```